# jQuery append to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append all values from a table to a variable (then the variable will be added to a field).
I don't manage to do that, so for now my solution has been to create an intermediary field :

```
var field = $('textarea');

$("#table .row").each(function () { 
  value = $(this).find('input').val() + '<br>';
  field.val(field.val() + value);
});

var myfinalvariable = othervariable + 'content' + field.val();
```

This works, but it obliged me to create a textarea field just for this purpose. Ideally, i'd just like to get rid of it by creating a variable that would replace field.val(). I tried many things, for example :

```
var content = '';

$("#table .row").each(function () { 
  value = $(this).find('input').val() + '<br>';
  var content = $(content) + value;
});

var myfinalvariable = othervariable + 'randomtext' + content;
```

Is there a problem with the syntax of with the logic ? I also tried .append() but with no success.

Thank you !

Comment: `content += value;` or `content = content + value;`  No `var` since you want to use the content variable defined previously.  No `$(thing)`, since that would be a jquery object wrapping a dom element matching the css selector found in the variable `thing`.

Comment: Please provide some HTML. See [ask]. Also revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Thank you so much @James . i struggled for more than an hour on this and i was so close the whole time...